# select distinct(date) return the same date several time

Tags: sql, oracle, date, distinct

On my Oracle database, I have a table with a column with `Date` as data type.

When I do this :

```
select distinct(MY_DATE) from MY_TABLE where extract(year from MY_DATE) = 2014;
```

I get this :

[image: Result]

And when I do this query :

```
select MY_DATE from MY_TABLE where extract(year from MY_DATE) = 2014;
```

That's what I have :

[image: Result]

I guess it's because of the different seconds and milliseconds.

How to ignore the time in date to have only one result in my fisrt query ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try the Query below, which just adds `TRUNC()` to your date column before taking a `DISTINCT` of it.

```
select distinct(TRUNC(MY_DATE)) from MY_TABLE where extract(year from MY_DATE) = 2014;
```

This is because the time factor in your column data is not the same.

`TRUNC()` will nullify the time element, retaining the date only

The query will actually reveal it. `TO_CHAR()` to output the date saved in the format specified.

```
select TO_CHAR(MY_DATE,'MM-DD-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') from MY_TABLE where extract(year from MY_DATE) = 2014;
```

More about `TRUNC` from [Oracle Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions201.htm)

Comment: column type is `DATE`, but `select TO_CHAR(MY_DATE,'MM-DD-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')` indeed gives time with hour, e.g. `01-02-1970 08:00:00`. How should I update it to 0 hour, e.g. `01-02-1970 00:00:00` then? Running `update ... set ... = '02-JAN-70'` won't update the 8:00 row as it is the same date.

Answer (score -3):

```
select distinct(date(MY_DATE)) from MY_TABLE where extract(year from MY_DATE) = 2014;
```

Comment: You should provide some explanation. Your answer looks like copy-and-paste from the previous answer.

Comment: @konekoya - I don't think it's just copy and pasted, as this answer is doing `select distinct(date...` as opposed to `select distinct(TRUNC...`, but yes, some explanation as to why that's better would be a good idea.

Comment: instead of truncate you can convert datetime into date only by using date() function then why you go for truncate..@konekoya