# Selecting distinct timestamps from an ORACLE database

Tags: sql, oracle, greatest-n-per-group

I am trying to limit the amount of data I pull in prior to processing/analysing it in python.
Mainly due to memory constraints.

Each transaction results in ~3-4 different transaction_events.

```
-----------
trx_id     timestamp
trx_1    | 2021.01.01 15:45:40
trx_1_2  | 2021.01.01 15:45:40
trx_1_3  | 2021.01.01 15:45:40
trx_2    | 2021.02.01 14:15:40
trx_2_2  | 2021.02.01 14:15:40
trx_2_3  | 2021.02.01 14:15:40
```

All I need is 1 record per timestamp.

```
-----------
trx_id   timestamp
trx_1  | 2021.01.01 15:45:40
trx_2  | 2021.02.01 14:15:40
```

I've already tried the following suggestions:

[On the ORACLE community forum](https://community.oracle.com/tech/developers/discussion/855891/selecting-a-distinct-date-from-a-timestamp-column)

and

[select distinct(date) return the same date several time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25239444/select-distinctdate-return-the-same-date-several-time)

I've tried various variations too

```
SELECT DISTINCT TRUNC(timestamp, 'DD')
```

```
SELECT DISTINCT TRUNC(timestamp)
```

```
SELECT DISTINCT to_char(timestamp, 'yyyy-mm-dd')
```

However with no results.

Comment: Instead of links to something that didn't help, I'd rather see some sample data which says what you have and what you want to do with it. SELECTs you posted dont "limit" anything so I have difficulties in understanding the problem.

Comment: @Littlefoot I've added some sample data and expected result.

Comment: If there are three `trx_id` values with the same timestamp (assuming they are the same - you haven't shown fractional seconds), how will you decide which one to show?

Comment: Is the `timestamp` you're referring to an actual [timestamp](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/Data-Types.html#GUID-94A82966-D380-4583-9AF1-AEE681881E64), or is it a `date`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `ROW_NUMBER` analytic function and partition by the first 5 characters of the `TRX_ID` and the timestamp:

```sql
SELECT trx_id, ts
FROM   (
  SELECT t.*,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
           PARTITION BY SUBSTR( trx_id, 1, 5 ), ts ORDER BY trx_id
         ) AS rn
  FROM   table_name t
)
WHERE  rn = 1;
```

Which, for your sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name ( trx_id, ts ) AS
SELECT 'trx_1',   TIMESTAMP '2021-01-01 15:45:40' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'trx_1_2', TIMESTAMP '2021-01-01 15:45:40' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'trx_1_3', TIMESTAMP '2021-01-01 15:45:40' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'trx_2',   TIMESTAMP '2021-02-01 14:15:40' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'trx_2_2', TIMESTAMP '2021-02-01 14:15:40' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'trx_2_3', TIMESTAMP '2021-02-01 14:15:40' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | TRX_ID | TS |
> | --- | --- |
> | trx_1 | 2021-01-01 15:45:40.000000000 |
> | trx_2 | 2021-02-01 14:15:40.000000000 |

If you can have other `TRX_ID` with different length patterns then you can look for the second underscore character and get the substring before that:

```sql
SELECT trx_id, ts
FROM   (
  SELECT t.*,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
           PARTITION BY CASE INSTR( trx_id, '_', 1, 2 )
                        WHEN 0
                        THEN trx_id
                        ELSE SUBSTR( trx_id, 1, INSTR( trx_id, '_', 1, 2 ) - 1 )
                        END,
                        ts
           ORDER     BY trx_id
         ) AS rn
  FROM   table_name t
)
WHERE  rn = 1;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=bd3f6780fda5d3c7976e5bccbe688cfe)*

Comment: I'm only given access to the table views rather than actual tables, and I'm pretty sure I cannot partition a view?

Comment: @little_adventurer You are not changing anything on the table or view; analytic functions can work over one window of the entire set of rows or can work on multiple sub-windows defined by the partition clause but that is internal to the function and does not change the underlying data. Why don't you just try the query and see if it solves your problem?

Comment: This solution won't work either. The trx_id structure I posted is arbitrary.
In reality they're random(ish) sequence of numbers with increment of 1 for the same timestamp.

I posted trx_1, trx_1_2 as an example of having 3 events for the same transaction with the (seemingly) same timestamp

Comment: @little_adventurer Then [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/67500920/edit) your question and give an appropriate [MRE] including **MORE REPRESENTATIVE** examples of your data and the appropriate expected output for that updated data. I do not know how you expect us to guess what a solution is to your question when you give some sample data and then say that your sample data is not entirely appropriate but do not tell us what is appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

You can use aggregation:

```
select min(trx_id), timestamp
from t
group by timestamp;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=593112aa6e47a16230049d8d6bde2a0f) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: What happens if there are two `trx_id` with the same timestamp? [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=9e0d8fc309a5bfcc140b00cefa396fa7)

Comment: @MT0 . . . You would need to ask the OP.  The question is explicitly:  "All I need is 1 record per timestamp.".